# Heroku run rake assets:precompile is FAILING? (can't dump anonymous class)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, asset-pipeline

Here is the trace output: What is this: `can't dump anonymous class` stuff? No idea what else I can try. I really welcome your help. Thank you!!

```
heroku run rake assets:precompile --trace
Running `rake assets:precompile --trace` attached to terminal... up, run.1662
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute assets:precompile
I, [2014-10-17T01:54:29.696549 #2]  INFO -- : Writing /app/public/assets/10code-7079b1d91d9d7c7a9a2338cea73f8a82.jpg
I, [2014-10-17T01:54:29.698443 #2]  INFO -- : Writing /app/public/assets/favicon-a74691afc8a111f00d70667670a61182.ico
I, [2014-10-17T01:54:37.258312 #2]  INFO -- : Writing /app/public/assets/application-16c68220ab8dd6d871a35138ee0901f0.js
Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 377616f718d2970e646cd030c1890fad19bd5c36/about.css.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #<Class:0x007f7cefb6b200>

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 377616f718d2970e646cd030c1890fad19bd5c36/blog.css.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #<Class:0x007f7cefb6b200>

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 377616f718d2970e646cd030c1890fad19bd5c36/contact.css.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #<Class:0x007f7cefb6b200>

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 302a764321a9d0728b3e071c26d4a8996eeed852/footer.css.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #<Class:0x007f7cefb6b200>

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 302a764321a9d0728b3e071c26d4a8996eeed852/navigation.css.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #<Class:0x007f7cefb6b200>

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 377616f718d2970e646cd030c1890fad19bd5c36/portfolio.css.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #<Class:0x007f7cefb6b200>

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 377616f718d2970e646cd030c1890fad19bd5c36/resources.css.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #<Class:0x007f7cefb6b200>

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 377616f718d2970e646cd030c1890fad19bd5c36/resume.css.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #<Class:0x007f7cefb6b200>

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 377616f718d2970e646cd030c1890fad19bd5c36/welcome.css.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #<Class:0x007f7cefb6b200>

rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
  (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/sass_functions.rb:63:in `sprockets_context'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/sass_functions.rb:38:in `font_path'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:140:in `_perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/script/tree/node.rb:50:in `perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:392:in `visit_return'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:8:in `visit'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:248:in `block (3 levels) in perform_sass_fn'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:248:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:248:in `block (2 levels) in perform_sass_fn'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:247:in `catch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:247:in `block in perform_sass_fn'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:84:in `perform_arguments'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:244:in `perform_sass_fn'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:131:in `_perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/script/tree/node.rb:50:in `perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/script/tree/operation.rb:64:in `_perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/script/tree/node.rb:50:in `perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:458:in `visit_variable'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:315:in `block (2 levels) in visit_import'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:315:in `map'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:315:in `block in visit_import'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/stack.rb:88:in `block in with_import'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/stack.rb:88:in `with_import'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:312:in `visit_import'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:315:in `block (2 levels) in visit_import'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:315:in `map'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:315:in `block in visit_import'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/stack.rb:88:in `block in with_import'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/stack.rb:88:in `with_import'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:312:in `visit_import'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `block in visit_children'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `map'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `visit_children'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:167:in `block in visit_children'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:179:in `with_environment'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:166:in `visit_children'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `block in visit'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:186:in `visit_root'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:157:in `visit'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:8:in `visit'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in `css_tree'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.5/lib/sass/engine.rb:268:in `render'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:24:in `evaluate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:25:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:211:in `block in find_asset'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:257:in `benchmark'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:210:in `find_asset'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:119:in `block in compile'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `compile'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.0.0.beta1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:70:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:146:in `with_logger'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.0.0.beta1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

Comment: Check this out as a possible issue if you are using SASS:  [Asset compiling crashing on server][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809432/asset-compiling-crashing-on-server-environment-with-nomethoderror-undefined-m

Comment: Looks like your issue is here: `NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass(in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)`. Can you include the application.css?

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me before, it ended up being invalid CSS which didn't flag locally in dev mode. If you compile locally it should give you some additional information about what the error is.

```
RAILS_ENV=production bin/rake assets:precompile
```

The last time I had this issue it was because of a missing colon.