# NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass when pushing to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Rails noob here.

I ran into a problem when pushing to Heroku (NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass). I'm not even sure where I should start looking to correct this problem.

```
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        I, [2015-10-04T23:27:47.570225 #397]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_1a2df3ea1a8121d7fba6ab542c59ba85/public/assets/application-7fbbda11565ec9a0d53aaeb338357988655d4d81476f99312f8a66772c63bea9.js
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
remote:        /tmp/build_1a2df3ea1a8121d7fba6ab542c59ba85/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.5/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:266:in `sprockets_context'
remote:
```

Comment: Can you run heroku logs --tail and post the full stack trace?

Answer (score 9):

I was able to resolve this problem by renaming my application.css file to application.css.scss.

Comment: Worked for me! It's probably due this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809432/asset-compiling-crashing-on-server-environment-with-nomethoderror-undefined-m.