# Javascript is not working on Heroku but works locally, how do I solve this?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I was able to push my code and deploy to Heroku, beforehand it was working locally on Cloud9. I hooked up the buildpacks for ruby on rails and add a postgres db to avoid deploy errors. When I looked at the deployed code, the javascript for my pages were disabled.

I have tried getting rid of the //= tree required in my application.rb file, removing the gemlock file, installing a sass alternative since the current one is depreciated, heroku asset clean and restart. And ran rake assets:precompile for both local and heroku

This is after `heroku run rake assets:precompile`

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:278:in `sprockets_context'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:124:in `asset_path'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:137:in `asset_url'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:209:in `font_url'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:151:in `block in _perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/stack.rb:108:in `block in with_function'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/stack.rb:135:in `with_frame'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/stack.rb:108:in `with_function'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:149:in `_perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/script/tree/node.rb:50:in `perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/script/tree/list_literal.rb:75:in `block in _perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/script/tree/list_literal.rb:75:in `map'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/script/tree/list_literal.rb:75:in `_perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/script/tree/node.rb:50:in `perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:398:in `visit_prop'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/stack.rb:135:in `with_frame'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:513:in `block (2 levels) in visit_directive'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:513:in `map'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:513:in `block in visit_directive'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:179:in `with_environment'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:512:in `visit_directive'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/stack.rb:135:in `with_frame'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `block in visit_children'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `map'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `visit_children'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:167:in `block in visit_children'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:179:in `with_environment'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:166:in `visit_children'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `block in visit'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:186:in `visit_root'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:157:in `visit'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:10:in `visit'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in `css_tree'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/engine.rb:290:in `render'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:48:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:134:in `block in find'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:133:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:133:in `find'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:186:in `compile'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:360:in `exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:444:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:10:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:121:in `with_friendly_errors'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

I was looking to have a fully functional site, but the push to heroku seemed to cause the application to not have any javascript functionality, when it should be. Please help, sorry for the annoying posts but I really want to get this down.

Comment: This post may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32939496/nomethoderror-undefined-method-for-nilnilclass-when-pushing-to-heroku

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rails-bootstrap gem, there is a file named bootstrap.coffee.js. You can try removing it and see if it works.

Also, You can also try pushing it in this manner(precompiling before pushing it to heroku):

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
git add .
git commit -a -m "JS"
git push heroku master
```

Other than that if none of it is working, from config/environments/production.rb:

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

The last approach is not advised.

Comment: I tried  ``` rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production``` and ```$RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile --trace ``` both compiled corrected and gave a green light but the javascript isnt working still. I also renamed all my .css to .scss files. I tried ```config.assets.compile=true``` in the production.rb, and it still didnt do anything. Any clue to what else might be wrong? What would be helpful to see?

Comment: I tried using a CDN line to access Jquery and it worked only for my bootstrap carousel, would it be something with the asset pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was missing the correct files in my `assets.rb` and `application.js` files. After that I precompiled and pushed as mentioned above and it worked! Thank you guys for the help!